# Updating models with dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel

I converting my models and controllers to support dependency injection, its working out pretty well but i'm struggling a bit with one thing. How do i go about updating my repository instances? Say i Have the following code:

```
$upload = Upload::find($id);
$upload->receiver_email_id = $mailAdress->id;
$upload->sender_email_id = $mailAdress2->id;
$saved = $upload->save();
```

So i get the Model, update the email_id and save it again. Now how does it go with dependency injection?

```
$upload = $this->upload->find($id);
```

So now i have my model. now what is the most elegant way to update it?
Something like:

```
$upload->update(array(
    'receiver_email_id' => $mailAdress->id,
    'sender_email_id' => $mailAdress2->id
));
```

or something like

```
$upload->receiver_email_id = $mailAdress->id;
$upload->sender_email_id = $mailAdress2->id;
$saved = $upload->save($upload);
```

where i pass the complete upload object and handle the save in the repository?

No idea why i'm struggling with this. Or maybe i'm overcomplicating things and there is a simple solution?

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you really want to do, but it seems that you are overcomplicating things. DI in a nutshell is just to use one class inside another class so that it can works.

So if you have a custom class (UploadService) and your other class (Upload) needs that class to work, just boot it up via a __constructor method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you how you structure your repositories. I tend to use your first approach mainly with my repository looking something like this

```
class UploadRepository {

    public function findById($id)
    {
        $upload = Upload::find($id);

        if ( ! $upload )
            throw new NotFoundException("Upload model with id:$id was not found");

        return $upload;
    }

    public function update($id, array $data)
    {
        $upload = $this->findById($id);

        $upload->update($data);

        $this->validate($upload->toArray());

        return $upload->save();
    }

    public function validate(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data);

        if ($validator->fails())
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }
}
```

Obviously pad out the repo with other methods you need but this way you can simply pass in the results of `Input::all()` to the repo from the controller.

```
// Considering this a resource controller
class UploadController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(UploadRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        return $this->repo->update($id, Input::all());
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Both of your approaches are correct and i don't see any problem at all.

if you have an array of items, you can simply use `update()` which can save few lines of code.

```
$upload->update(Input::all());
```

On the other hand, if you have some variables and wants to update the model, the best way to do it by assigning them to the model object.

```
$upload->receiver_email_id = $mailAdress->id;
$upload->sender_email_id = $mailAdress2->id;
$upload->save();
```